# How to get call duration in asterisk from start of a particular context and end?

Tags: asterisk

I am able to get call duration using CDR(billsec) which gives me complete call duration (i.e the moment it was answered till hangup).

I have a requirement where I need call duration of a particular context. The time internal to asterisk from start of that call context until end.

Answer (score 2):

You also have CDR(duration) which show you unanswered(overal ) lenght

If you need split your cdr, you have do it yourself in dialplan like

```
exten => _X.,n,Set(CDR(start_here)=${STRFTIME(,%c)})
; need start_here field in cdr table
```

or you can use ForkCDR/ResetCDR.

Other complex option is asterisk manager interface(AMI) events or channel level logging(CEL)

Anyway there are no easy context-independed way, becuase one context can include other.

Comment: I used exten => s,n,ResetCDR(w) and it worked.Thanks a lot for your answer and the usual support of stack overflow !!!!